# SQL Server: compare time in two tables and remove from match process once row matched

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `T1` and `T2`, each with two columns `Group` and `Time`.

I would like to match each time value in `T1` with the closest time in `T2`,
but once a time is chosen as the closest time from `T2` it is removed from the
matching process (this is really important!). Additionally, two times are only
matched if they belong to the same group.

See the two tables, `T1` and `T2`, below:

```
 T1.Group | T1.Time1         |
----------+------------------+
     A    | 2020-01-01 10:00 |
     A    | 2020-01-01 10:01 |
     B    | 2020-01-01 16:07 |
     A    | 2020-01-02 20:25 |
     A    | 2020-01-03 07:45 |
     B    | 2020-01-05 00:07 |
     A    | 2020-01-03 07:49 |


 T2.Group | T2.Time2         |
----------+------------------+
     B    | 2020-01-05 23:00 |
     A    | 2020-01-01 11:24 |
     A    | 2020-01-01 13:00 |
     A    | 2020-01-02 20:45 |
     A    | 2020-01-03 08:10 |
     A    | 2020-01-04 12:10 |
     B    | 2020-01-06 17:49 |
```

The result I want is this:

```
 Result.Group | Result.Time1     | Result.Time2     |
--------------+------------------+------------------+
       A      | 2020-01-01 10:00 | 2020-01-01 11:24 |
       A      | 2020-01-01 10:01 | 2020-01-01 13:00 |
       A      | 2020-01-02 20:25 | 2020-01-02 20:45 |
       A      | 2020-01-03 07:45 | 2020-01-03 08:10 |
       A      | 2020-01-03 07:49 | 2020-01-04 12:10 |
       B      | 2020-01-01 16:07 | 2020-01-05 23:00 |
       B      | 2020-01-05 00:07 | 2020-01-06 17:49 |
```

I have no idea how to solve this in SQL (I know how to do it, if I don't remove a row from the matching process once matched, but this is not what I want). Hope you can help. Thanks :)

Comment: What happens when times don't match?  Do the times have to be in any particular order?

Comment: If there really isn't a match, let's say there are less rows in T2 than T1, then a null is returned (kind of a left join). Time is only ordered when matched (finding the closest times). I mean, you could also return the result in an ordered fashion, but it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to assign one value from `t2` to `t1`, then you can assign them in order:

```
select t1.*, t2.time2
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by group order by time1) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by group order by time2) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.group = t2.group and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

`group` is a really bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword and reserved word.  I assume that the actual column has a more reasonable name.

This works for the data you provided and seems like a reasonable interpretation of the question (given the data).  However, it might not fully answer your question, but you have not provided the additional details that are needed.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e37a6c84b0b48f5a385109a62d3afe56) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @SteveC . . . I'm not sure what you are referring to.  The Fiddle uses `grp`, but the OP has `group`.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks for your reply. This doesn't solve the problem of "matching the closest time". It might work for this small test data, but it won’t work in general.  You basically just give table T1 a sequence column and table T2 a sequence column and then you match those sequence numbers for both columns. What I am interested in is finding the closest time for each time in T2 by each time in T1. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

What you will probably need is a new common row when any of the two tables experience a change , that is, a new date for the same group. For example, t2 undergoes two changes while t1 undergoes only one , starting with '2020-01-01 10:01:00'.

To get there, I actually add a new column, to_time1, to t1 and to_time2, to t2, Then I join over `grp`, (I renamed that , too), and a cross-comparison of the now 2 dates.

See here:

```
WITH
-- your input ...
t1(grp,time1) AS (
          SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 10:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 10:01'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 16:07'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-02 20:25'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-03 07:45'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-05 00:07'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-03 07:49'
)
,
t2(grp,time2) AS (
          SELECT 'B', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-05 23:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 11:24'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 13:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-02 20:45'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-03 08:10'
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-04 12:10'
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-06 17:49'
)
-- add a to_time to both tables, and 9999-12-31 to the newest row ...
,
t1slice AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , IFNULL(LEAD(time1) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY time1),'9999-12-31') AS to_time1
FROM t1
)
,
t2slice AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , IFNULL(LEAD(time2) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY time2),'9999-12-31') AS to_time2
FROM t2
)
-- join the two enriched tables over an equi predicate on `grp` 
-- and a cross-compare of the valid-from / valid-to dates
SELECT
  t1slice.grp
, t1slice.time1
, t2slice.time2
FROM t1slice
JOIN t2slice USING(grp)
WHERE t1slice.time1 < t2slice.to_time2
  AND t2slice.time2 < t1slice.to_time1
ORDER BY 1,2
;
-- out  grp |        time1        |        time2        
-- out -----+---------------------+---------------------
-- out  A   | 2020-01-01 10:01:00 | 2020-01-01 11:24:00
-- out  A   | 2020-01-01 10:01:00 | 2020-01-01 13:00:00
-- out  A   | 2020-01-02 20:25:00 | 2020-01-01 13:00:00
-- out  A   | 2020-01-02 20:25:00 | 2020-01-02 20:45:00
-- out  A   | 2020-01-03 07:45:00 | 2020-01-02 20:45:00
-- out  A   | 2020-01-03 07:49:00 | 2020-01-02 20:45:00
-- out  A   | 2020-01-03 07:49:00 | 2020-01-03 08:10:00
-- out  A   | 2020-01-03 07:49:00 | 2020-01-04 12:10:00
-- out  B   | 2020-01-05 00:07:00 | 2020-01-05 23:00:00
-- out  B   | 2020-01-05 00:07:00 | 2020-01-06 17:49:00
```

Comment: Hi Marco. Thanks for your reply. This doen't seem to give the right result. It should give 7 rows not 10. I have translated your query (Oracle?) to SQL server. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=05eae095b7b9b4f886edeb6af621b121